# $S^3$ hyperspherical harmonics in terms of spherical harmonics

Tags: harmonic-analysis, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

In a problem I might want to work one, I would find myself having to work explicitly with hyperspherical harmonics on a three-sphere and their tensor decomposition. It’s well known that $S^3$ can be expressed as the total space of a non-trivial $U(1)$ bundle over the sphere $S^2$.  My question is whether someone has tried to extend the spherical harmonics $Y_{lm}$ on $S^2$ to hyperspherical harmonics by replacing them with suitable sections of a bundle over the $S^2$ base?

Comment: I know people have computed the Laplace spectrum of Berger spheres, the spectrum of $S^3$ is a special case of this. What benefit would a link to the two-dimensional spherical harmonics give you that you don't have working with harmonic polynomials in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: Mainly that I the computation is abstract. Let’s say I have a basis T_i of trace less symmetric polynomials, then I have to evaluate things like \int [T_i T_j T_k T_l ] which is a very complicated Wigner j symbol like object. The group theory of SU(2) is just simpler than SO(4).

Comment: I think for $S^3$ in particular its spherical harmonics coincide with irreducible representations of $SU(2)$, no need to put things in terms of the 2-dimensional spherical harmonics. But I'm out of my depth on the group theory side of global harmonic analysis.